# Bind Delete key to delete character at cursor in ksh

Tags: keyboard, shell

In a QNX Neutrino shell I need to use, the delete key doesn't work appropriately. I get a ~ when I press it.

My end goal is to get Delete, Home, and End keys on the keyboard to behave as they do in Windows command shell.

How do I bind the "Delete the character at the cursor" to the Delete keyboard button?  My attempts at using an alias were unsucessful.

Notes that may or may not matter, but could provide background:

- This is PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2
- Control-D behaves like I expect the delete button to work.
- bind shows the following:

> ```
> bind | grep del
> ^D = eot-or-delete
> ^H = delete-char-backward
> ^? = delete-char-backward
> ^[^H = delete-word-backward
> ^[d = delete-word-forward
> ^[h = delete-word-backward
> ^[^? = delete-word-backward
> ^XP = delete-char-forward
> à¬ = delete-char-forward
> ```

- infocmp shows the following:

> ```
> infocmp
>  #      Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/lib/terminfo/x/xterm
> xterm|vs100|xterm terminal emulator,
>         am, km, mir, msgr, xenl, xon,
>         cols#80, it#8, lines#65, vt@,
>         acsc=Oa``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
>         bel=^G, blink=@, bold=\E[1m, clear=\E[H\E[2J, cr=^M,
>         csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H,
>         cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=\E[B, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
>         cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
>         dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM, dl1=\E[M, ed=\E[J,
>         el=\E[K, el1=\E[1K$<3>, enacs=\E(B\E)0, home=\E[H, ht=^I,
>         hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@, ich1=\E[2~, il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L,
>         ind=^J, is1=\E=\E[?1l, kBEG=\ENn, kCPY=\ENs, kCRT=\ENt,
>         kDL=\ENv, kEXT=\ENw, kFND=\ENx, kHLP=\ENy, kOPT=\ENz,
>         ka3=\EOs, kb2=\EOr, kbs=^H, kc1=\EOq, kcan=\EOm, kclo=\ENc,
>         kclr=\ENa, kcmd=\EOu, kcub1=\E[D, kcud1=\E[B, kcuf1=\E[C,
>         kcuu1=\E[A, kdch1=\E[P, kend=\E[9, kf1=\E[11~, kf10=\E[21~,
>         kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~, kf2=\E[12~, kf3=\E[13~,
>         kf4=\E[14~, kf5=\E[15~, kf6=\E[17~, kf7=\E[18~, kf8=\E[19~,
>         kf9=\E[20~, kfnd=\ENf, khlp=\ENh, khome=\E[8, khts=\ENb,
>         kich1=\E[2~, kmov=\ENi, kmrk=\ENm, kmsg=\ENe, knp=\E[6~,
>         kopn=\ENo, kopt=\ENk, kpp=\E[5~, kref=\ENl, kres=\ENp,
>         krfr=\ENg, krpl=\ENr, krst=\ENj, ksav=\ENq, kslt=\EOM,
>         ktbc=\ENd, kund=\ENu, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM, rmacs=^O,
>         rmam=\E[?7l, rmkx=\E>, rmso=\E[m,
>         rs1=\E>\E[1;3;4;5;6l\E[?7h\E[m\E[r\E[2J\E[H, rs2=@,
>         sc=\E7,
>         setb=\E[4%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,
>         setf=\E[3%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,
>         sgr=\E[0%?%p1%p6%|%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;m,
>         sgr0=\E[m, smacs=^N, smam=\E[?7h, smkx=\E=, smso=\E[7m,
>         tbc=\E[3g,
> ```

- stty shows the following:

> ```
> stty
> Name:  /dev/ttyp0
> Type:  pseudo
> Opens: 2
> +edit +echok +echonl
> +osflow
>  intr=^C  quit=^\ erase=^?  kill=^U   eof=^D start=^Q  stop=^S  susp=^Z
> lnext=^V   min=01  time=00   pr1=^[   pr2=5B  left=44 right=43    up=41
>  down=42   ins=40   del=50  home=48   end=59
> ```

- Control A and Control E behave like I would like the Home and End keys to

Hopefully this is really easy points for someone... I just don't know enough of how to put this together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Googlers:

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66434/delete-key-doesnt-work-on-command-line

```
bind '^[[3'=prefix-2
bind '^[[3~'=delete-char-forward
```